# measurable function from $S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle identified as $[0,1)$ with addition modulo 1. Let $0 <\alpha<1$ be an irrational number and let $\tau$ be the irrational rotation by $\alpha $ defined by $\tau(x)=x+\alpha~~ mod ~~~1$. Let $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $f(x)=1$ if $0\leq x <\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $\frac{1}{2}\leq x<1$. Let $x,x' \in S^1$ such that $x \neq x'$. I want to prove that there exists $n\geq 0$ such that $f(\tau^n(x))\neq f(\tau^n(x'))$. Clearly if $0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\leq x'<1$ or vice versa then we can take $n=0$. How can we take $n$ if both $x, x' \in [0,\frac{1}{2})$ or $[\frac{1}{2},1)$. Certainly in this case $f(x)=f(x')$ so $n>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supose $0 \le x < x' < \tfrac{1}{2}$. Since $\alpha$ is irrational, $\{\tau^{-n}(\tfrac{1}{2})\mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ is dense in $[0,1)$, so we can find $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $x < \tau^{-n}(\tfrac{1}{2}) < x'$. It's not hard to see now that $0<\tau^n(x) < \tfrac{1}{2} < \tau^n(x')<1$.

I leave the details to you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Surely I can do the details.

Comment: Why the above set is dense? I know any subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is either cyclic or dense. Can we apply this to the quotient $S^1$ to prove it?

Comment: Does $\tau$ preserve the order?Why does the inequality came? I am sorry I couldnt fill the details.

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer please. I think I am not understanding the modulo notation of $S^1$ properly

Comment: I know that $\tau$ is not order preserving, the only rotation that is order preserving is the identity. But you only need it to preserve the order of certain elements.

Comment: For $\alpha = 1/\sqrt{2}$, $x=1/5$ and $x'=1/3$ we have $1/5<\tau^{-6}(1/2)<1/3$. The rotation $\tau^6(x)$ is equivalent to a rotation of $6/\sqrt{2} \bmod  1 = .2426\ldots$, so $\tau^6(x)$ applied to the interval $[1/5,1/3]$ doesn't "go around 1" and hence is order preserving.

Comment: $\tau^{-n}(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}-n\alpha~mod~1(\frac{1}{2}-n\alpha or \frac{1}{2}-n\alpha+1 )$. Am I right? So $x< \tau^{-n}(\frac{1}{2})$ implies $x < \frac{1}{2}-n\alpha $ or $x < \frac{1}{2}-n\alpha +1$. In the first case $x < \frac{1}{2}-n\alpha $ implies $x +n\alpha< \frac{1}{2}$ and so $\tau^n(x)<\frac{1}{2}$. Now if  $x < \frac{1}{2}-n\alpha +1$, then $x+n\alpha<\frac{3}{2}$. But I also need to see that $x+n\alpha>1$ so that in this case also $\tau^n(x)=x+n\alpha-1<\frac{1}{2}$. But that will follow since $\tau^{-n}(\frac{1}{2})<\frac{1}{2}$. Am I correct?

Comment: I could understand that the set $\{\tau^m(\frac{1}{2}): m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense. But can we vary $m$ only in $\mathbb{N}$ to get a dense set?